# Async await not working with 'then' and 'catch'

Tags: javascript

There are two scenarios in my case.

[image: code]

In the first case the code is working fine.

Why is it throwing an error in this case. Can't I use await in `then` or is there a problem with using try catch inside the `then` statement?

[image: code]

I should also mention that the platform that I am coding in is a little different but it accepts pure JavaScript too.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question and not just as linked images.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: Could you maybe give a bit more context information?

Comment: Why not use try - catch blocks?

Comment: use try catch with await or promise.then().catch() with promises.

Answer (score 0):

Await will already resolve your promise, so "then" wont be having any promise to resolve.

For await async try this

```
    private myMethod = async () => {
   try {
      const response = await yourPromise();
   } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
   }
}
```